# Python - Assign class attribute to a variable

Tags: python, list, oop, variables, methods

I am making a dictionay like app, and depending of the Translation switch, the screen displays the translation or the original word
The code looks like this:

PS: "textFunction(text)" is just a function that displays text to screen.
PS: "wordList" is a list of Word Class intances

```
class Word:
  def __init__(self, original, translation):
      self.original = original
      self.translation = translation

translation = False
if translation == False:
    wordDisplayed = .original
elif translation == True:
    wordDisplayed = .translation

textFunction(wordList[X].wordDisplayed)
```

However, this gives me a syntax error. How could I code this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `getattr`:

```
wordDisplayed = "translation" if translation else "original"
textFunction(getattr(wordList[X], wordDisplayed))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch chepner! I'll mark your answer as correct ASAP

Answer (score 0):

While "getattr" is a possible solution, I'd say adding a `get` function to your class makes this all more readable and maintainable:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self, original, translation):
        self.original = original
        self.translation = translation
    def get(self, translation):
        return self.translation if translation else self.original

words = [Word("hello", "hallo"), Word("world", "Welt")]

for w in words:
    print(w.get(False), w.get(True))
```

Output:

```
hello hallo
world Welt
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mike! I'll try to implement it.
I'm kinda new to the whole OOP philosophy and the getter-setter functions.

Cheers!

Comment: `get` runs afoul of the "rule" that a function should do two different things based on a Boolean argument. Something like `def get(self, version): return self.translation if version == "translation" else self.original` is slightly better, as now the argument explicitly tells you more about what will happen. (But still compresses what should conceptually be two methods into one.)

Comment: @chepner IMHO it comes down to documentation. Personally, I think a string in this case leaves too much room for error, if the returned value can only be one of two values. But if f a mere positional argument isn't "that good", what about enforcing a named argument with ``def get(self, *, translation=False):`` - that way the caller would have to explicitely write ``w.get(translation=True)``, making it more obvious what you will get returned from the method.